# Lookup user's YouTube Account with Google Id

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, google-identity

I need to locate the user's YouTube account/channel Google user Id.

A Google Search on find YouTube channel from google id yields several StackeOverflow possible options, some use the Google+ API which has been deprecated, but I'm sure there are alternatives using the Google Identity API or some other Google API.

Can anyone give me idea or a solution about how can I convert Google Account Id to YouTube Channel Id Account?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that YouTube and google where originally two different companies there is probably no direct link that you are going to be able to hack your way to.

This is partly why (IMO) YouTube login is channel based.  A user can have more then one channel so your not going to be able to find a single channel for a user relation its going to be a one to many relation.  I dont think google has any way for you to see this without having the user login.

Your best option will be to ask the user to sign in and then use [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) with the option mine.